# how to create a generic table linked with multiple others using jpa

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

In a database there are several entities, each with its own table, like users, customers, companies and so on.
Each entity has a property like address, phone. These properties are stored under their specific table, like addresses, respectively phones.
I know that the fast approach would be to create distinct "sub-tables" for each entity, like usersAddresses, customersAddresses and so on, but I would like the single table approach.

Considering a setup like:

```
`
    @Entity
    public class Users implements Serializable{
        @Id
        private Integer userId;
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "connectedToTableId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "addresses.connectedToTableName", referencedColumnName = "'users'")
        })
        @OneToMany
        private List<Addresses> adressesList;
    }
    @Entity
    public class Customers implements Serializable{
        @Id
        private Integer customerId;
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "connectedToTableId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "addresses.connectedToTableName", referencedColumnName = "'customers'")
        })
        @OneToMany
        private List<Addresses> adressesList;
    }
    @Entity
    public class Addresses implements Serializable{
        @Id
        private Integer addressId;
        private String connectedToTableName;
        private int connectedToTableId;
    }
`
```

On a typical scenario with usersAddresses and customersAddresses there would be an easy direct mapping, but I want to know if it is possible to obtain some similar behavior using this design.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: You could use "The Single Table per Class Hierarchy Strategy" http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html#bnbqs, using a single table with a discriminator column.